# How to assign the enter key on my keyboard to a JButton

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I have created a Jframe with a JButton for a specific action.
Now please I want a situation whereby anytime I hit my enter key on my keyboard it will perform the action I have coded in my Jbutton.
My Jframe was designed with Netbeans 7.3.

Comment: I am sorry.I do not mean to shout

Comment: All forgiven.  Hope you get a good answer.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now please I want a situation whereby anytime I hit my enter key on my keyboard it will perform the action I have coded in my Jbutton.

- Make your JButton the default button of the JRootPane.
- You do this by calling `setDefaultButton(myJButton)` on the root pane.
- And you can get the JRootPane by calling `getRootPane()` on your JFrame.
- Note that if you want this action when a JTextField has focus, then the solution is different; here you'll want to add the same ActionListener given to the JButton to the JTextField.

Comment: Thank You for your answer but I am having challenges with it.

Comment: initComponents();
         getRootPane().setDefaultButton(connectButton);

Comment: what issues are you having?

Comment: By using the above code i stated,The enter key worked but my cursor tab must be in the botton. I want a situation where the action will be performed regardless of the position of my cursor.Imagine I am filling a form and after entering my full names in one of the text field,i decide to ignore other fields and want to summit the form by just hitting my ENTER key to act accordingly with the summit bottton.

Comment: @GstuntzWonderz: no the cursor doesn't have to be on the JButton for this to work, but it can't be inside of a JTextComponent or other component that has an innate response to a press of the enter button. I've given a solution in my answer above for when a JTextField has the focus; have you tried that?

Comment: I think the reason why I am finding this hard is because I am a beginner.I have been working on this for hours

Comment: @GstuntzWonderz: if still stuck, then consider creating a small Swing program, one not generated with the NetBeans code builder, that illustrates your problem for all of us to analyze and help with. Lacking this, I wonder if it is possible that we can guess what is wrong with your current code based on snippets of information and code.

Comment: OK.Let me quickly do that.Thanks

Answer (score -1):

**Implement ActionListener Interface**

> The listener interface for receiving action events. The class that is
>   interested in processing an action event implements this interface,
>   and the object created with that class is registered with a component,
>   using the component's addActionListener method. When the action event
>   occurs, that object's actionPerformed method is invoked.